# How to remove todo static analysis for Dart/Flutter projects?

Tags: flutter, dart, visual-studio-code

Dart and flutter have a static analysis linter/tool. Most of the time I find it useful, except for `TODO` comments in my code. I have a different way of tracking my todos in code (beyond the static analysis tool).

How can I disable this analysis for *all* my todo comments? I don't want to have to add an ignore statement (`ignore: todo`) for each item either, like below.

Example:

```dart
// I don't want to have to do this every time.

// ignore: todo
// TODO: implement rest of class
class SomeClass {
    Object someValue;
}
```

Comment: https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options

Comment: Thanks, pskink! I looked there earlier but not hard enough apparently. There is a section labeled *Ignoring rules* that I never made it to. Which, incidentally, has an example exactly for my case.

Comment: yes indeed, at first i even wanted to point to that section directly but i thought that it will be better when you read the whole page ;-)

Comment: Haha, I appreciate it then!

Comment: sure, your welcome

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The solution is on the [Linter for Dart: Ignoring rules (page)](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options#ignoring-rules).

You'll need to add an `analysis_options.yaml` file option at the root of your directory and add the following rules:

`analysis_options.yaml`

```yaml
analyzer:
  errors:
    todo: ignore
```

---

Credit goes to [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink) for making me look twice at the page (from the comment section).

> [dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options](https://dart.dev/guides/language/analysis-options) – [pskink](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2252830/pskink)

Comment: If you use VS Code and  the Dart-Code extension, you can add the following to you `settings.json` to disable only todos in your editor: `"dart.showTodos": false`.

Comment: This comment saved my day. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Moving @APEALED comment to be a top level answer, as it is the one that most helped me.

If you use VS Code and the Dart-Code extension, you can add the following to you settings.json to disable only todos in your editor: "dart.showTodos": false.